# Is there any way to remove where clause from query using logic?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I am getting the data from the controller.

**Model code**

```
 $select_filter_status=$parameters['select_filter_status'];
 $select_filter_action= $parameters['select_filter_action'];

if(($select_filter_status=='') && ($select_filter_action=='')){
       $where_2=" "; // I don't have any condition here. I have to display all the records

}
else if(($select_filter_status=='') || ($select_filter_action=='')){

        if ($select_filter_action=='') {
            $where_2="product_order.o_order_status=".$select_filter_status;
      }
      else{
            $where_2="product_order.o_order_status_confirm=".$select_filter_action;
      }
}
else{
        $where_2="product_order.o_order_status=".$select_filter_status." and product_order.o_order_status_confirm=".$select_filter_action;
  }




$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('tbl_customer');
$this->db->join('tbl_customer_billing', 'tbl_customer.cust_id=tbl_customer_billing.c_b_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('tbl_customer_shipping', 'tbl_customer.cust_id=tbl_customer_shipping.cust_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->where($com_report);
$this->db->where($where_2); // I want to remove this where clause when there is empty status and action
$this->db->order_by('product_order.o_date_of_added','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

My issue is, I have two where clause in the query and I have to remove the second `where condition` if `$select_filter_status` and `$select_filter_action`are found empty.

Is there any way to remove where clause or I have to use something like

```
if(){
//with two where clause
}
else{
//with one where clasue
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass the where_2 query in your main query.. concatinate the variable $where_2 in your $com_report query

```
if(($select_filter_status=='') && ($select_filter_action=='')){
       $where_2=" "; // I don't have any condition here. I have to display all the records

}
else if(($select_filter_status=='') || ($select_filter_action=='')){

        if ($select_filter_action=='') {
            $where_2="and product_order.o_order_status=".$select_filter_status;
      }
      else{
            $where_2="and product_order.o_order_status_confirm=".$select_filter_action;
      }
}
else{
        $where_2="and product_order.o_order_status=".$select_filter_status." and product_order.o_order_status_confirm=".$select_filter_action;
  }
```

**NOW**

```
$com_report ='your where statements ' .$where_2 ;
```

pass it to the query builder now

```
$this->db->where($com_report);
```

i hope it will work for you

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: alright :) btw you can check your query by ```$q = $this->db->last_query();``` and ```print_r($q);exit;``` to print it on the screen to see whats wrong with the query :)

Comment: Yes, your answer is working for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put only one if condition here like this. It will work for you.

```
if (!empty($where_2){
   $this->db->where($where_2);
}
```

if $where_2 is not empty it will execute second where condition, if it's empty it will ignore the second where.

Or you can concatenate the query string like this to use only one query clause

```
$com_report = $com_report . " " . $where_2;
```

Now no need for second where clause
Hope it will work for you

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: Your answer is also working for me. upvote from my side.

Comment: Can you help me in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745217/how-to-submit-the-dynamical-input-field-into-the-database

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add where clause based on condition in Codeigniter, Like this,

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('tbl_customer');
$this->db->join('tbl_customer_billing', 'tbl_customer.cust_id=tbl_customer_billing.c_b_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('tbl_customer_shipping', 'tbl_customer.cust_id=tbl_customer_shipping.cust_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->where($com_report);
if(!empty($select_filter_status) AND !empty($select_filter_action)){
    $this->db->where($where_2); 
}


$this->db->order_by('product_order.o_date_of_added','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

Comment: I thought I can't use like this because of wrong format.Give me some time to check