# How to submit the dynamical input field into the database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, codeigniter-3

I am displaying the input field dynamically which is working for me.

I have to submit the form. I have tried some code as below but it's not working.

I am using CodeIgniter.

**Controler code**

```
public function register(){
$save = array(
   'pp_fileStatus' => $this->input->post('pp_fileStatus');
   'reasonDate' => $this->input->post('reasonDate');
   'reasonAmt' => $this->input->post('reasonAmt');
 );
$afterxss=$this->security->xss_clean($save);
        if ($afterxss) 
        { 
          $this->db->insert('tbl_register',$afterxss);
            $response['error'] = "true";
            $response['msg']   = "Successfully";
        
      }else{
          $response['error'] = "false";
          $response['msg']   = "Sometning wrong! please check the internet connection and try again";
      } 
   echo json_encode($response);          
}
```

I am adding the field dynamically and incrementing the name. What name do I have to use here?

```
$save = array(
       'pp_fileStatus' => $this->input->post('pp_fileStatus');
       'reasonDate' => $this->input->post('reasonDate');
       'reasonAmt' => $this->input->post('reasonAmt');
     );
```

Below is the code for adding the input field dynamically.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
  var count = 2;
  var numberIncr = 1; // used to increment the name for the inputs
  var addrm = '';

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(document).on('click', '#clicktoadd', function() {
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++; //Increment field counter
      numberIncr++;
      $(".medication_info").append('<select name="pp_fileStatus' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled selected>Status</option><option value="1">Open</option><option value="2">Close</option><option value="3">Pending</option></select>');
    }
    count++;

  });
  $(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function(event) {

    if (($(this).val() == '1') || ($(this).val() == '3')) {
      $(".medication_info").append('<div class="addbankField input-wrapper padding0"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonDate' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control datetimepicker dynamicVal" placeholder="Date"></div></div><div class="addbankField input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonAmt' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control commnumber dynamicVal" placeholder="amt"></div></div><input type="hidden" name="remark' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control" placeholder="Remark">');
    } else {
      $(".medication_info").append('<div class="addbankField input-wrapper lbpflex padding0"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonDate' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control datetimepicker dynamicVal" placeholder="Date"></div></div><div class="addbankField input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="remark' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control dynamicVal" placeholder="Remark"></div></div><input type="hidden" name="reasonAmt' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control" placeholder="amt">');
    }
  });

});



$('#register').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // adding rules for inputs with class 'comment'
  $('.dynamicVal').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
      required: true
    })
  });
  // test if form is valid 
  if ($('#register').validate().form()) {
    $.ajax({
      //url:"process.php",
      url: baseUrl + "/Customer_control/register",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: $('#register').serialize(),

      success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
      },
    }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
  }
  //alert('hellow');
});
$('#register').validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.is("select")) {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<div id="clicktoadd"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-bg">Add More</a></div>
<form action="#" method="post" id="register" name="register">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medication_info">
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays for multiple names in HTML form and then get the values using Foreach Loop in PHP (CodeIgniter).

Here is how you should change your code: Change your this line:

```
$(".medication_info").append('<select name="pp_fileStatus' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled selected>Status</option><option value="1">Open</option><option value="2">Close</option><option value="3">Pending</option></select>')
```

To:

```
$(".medication_info").append('<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled selected>Status</option><option value="1">Open</option><option value="2">Close</option><option value="3">Pending</option></select>')
```

Note: I just changed **select field name to "pp_fileStatus[]"** and remove numberIncr variable

Now you can access this field name values in your controller like this.

```
$pp_fileStatus = $this->input->post('pp_fileStatus');
```

Here $pp_fileStatus is an array and contains all the values of pp_fileStatus.

**You can do same for your other form fields too**.

So you get rid of giving names to fields by incrementing one to a variable.

Hope this solves your problem.

You can update your register function like this:

```
public function register(){

    $insert_array = [];

    $pp_fileStatus = $this->input->post('pp_fileStatus');
    $reasonDate    = $this->input->post('reasonDate');
    $reasonAmt    = $this->input->post('reasonAmt');
    $remark    = $this->input->post('remark');

    foreach ($pp_fileStatus as $key => $value) {

        $insert_array[] = array(
                                   'pp_fileStatus' => $value,
                                   'reasonDate' => $reasonDate[$key],
                                   'reasonAmt' => $reasonAmt[$key],
                                   'remark' => $remark[$key]
                                 );

    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_register',$insert_array);
}
```

**Update this function according to your needs**

Comment: @Thanks for the answer, Give me some time to implement this answer with my code

Comment: sure, if you get any problem, you can ask here in comment.

Comment: Yes, I checked I am getting the value crrect. Like below Array
(
    [0] => 01-01
    [1] => 01-02
    [2] => 02-01
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)

Comment: Do I need to use any foreach condition to insert the datain to database?

Comment: You can use insert_batch() in codeIgniter if you want to insert more than one records

Comment: Give me some time to check again

Comment: Sure, I will accept it and upvote you but let me implement first with my code to check it's working or not.

Comment: I just want to know why you used if ($value == 1){ ? My data is dynamic. So how it will check? I think I don't think so I have to use if the condition here.

Comment: It is for in case you want different fields for open, close and pending. If you don't need if condition, you can simply remove it

Comment: Oh!..give me some time

Comment: I have updated my answer again, now check register function.

Comment: Yes, I tested and it's working perfectly. If I use PHP then instated of insert_batch what I have to use it?

Comment: If you want to use simple PHP query instead of insert_batch(), then you can use foreach loop on $insert_array and insert query inside that loop and insert record one by one through loop

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a function for your submit actions, which you call (*make available*) on document load and also with your change event, after having appended the DOM.

simplified example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  my_submit(); // enables your submit calls
  $(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function(event) {
    // your append code
    my_submit(); // again, enables your submit calls
  })
}
function my_submit(){
  $('#register').on('submit', function(event) {
    // your code
  })
  $('#register').validate({
    // your code
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I am getting the data on my controller. But I am getting only the first value. If I add 3 fields dynamically then I am getting only first field value. I know I have to use the foreach condition but how and what condition i have to use it?

Comment: If you notice. I am incrementing the name in the script. Is this best way to do?

Comment: @TufailAhmad, I apologize for this. I am stuck on this issue for the last 15 days. I tried whatever I understood but still not able to find the solution for it. One of the members suggest me to use validation like this for dyanmic.

Comment: @TufailAhmad, any more help in this?

Comment: Always use validation in the back-end i.e in your controller, JS validation can be fooled very easily.